# Definition of length of a curve

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

In the following definition of the length of a curve which is copied verbatim from this Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Definition_for_a_smooth_curve), I would like to know why the length of a line segment equals $ \big | f(t_i) - f(t_{i-1}) \big | $.

Here is the definition of the arc length from Wikipedia.

> Let $f\colon[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuously differentiable
>   function.  The length of the curve defined by $f$ can be defined as
>   the limit of the sum of line segment lengths for a regular partition
>   of $[a,b]$ as the number of segments approaches infinity.  This means
>
> $$L(f)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^N \bigg|f(t_i)-f(t_{i-1})\bigg|$$
>
> where $t_i=a+i(b-a)/N=a+i\Delta t$ for $i=0,1,\dotsc,N$.

It seems to me that $ \big | f(t_i) - f(t_{i-1}) \big | $ needs to be replaced with $ \big | (t_i, f(t_i)) - (t_{i-1}, f(t_{i-1})) \big | $ because the latter is the true length of a line segment, not the former.

For instance, for the case where $n = 1$ where we deal with a curve in the plane, if we let $y = f(x)$ then the length of a line segment should be $ \big | (t_i, f(t_i)) - (t_{i-1}, f(t_{i-1})) \big | $ which is equal to $\sqrt{(\Delta x)^2 + (\Delta y)^2}$, not just $ \big | f(t_i) - f(t_{i-1}) \big | $ which is the same as $\Delta y$.  Again the latter doesn't make sense to me as it only accounts for the increment in the value of $y$ and does not account for the increment in the value of $x$.

**Edit**: I understand that $\bf{f}$ is a vector-valued function with $n$ components.  But the curve (or the manifold) representing $\bf{f}$ exists in the $(n+1)$-dimensional space, and thus we need to find the distances (namely the line segment lengths) in the $(n+1)$-dimensional space, not in the $n$-dimensional space.  Thus $ \big | \big | \textbf{f} (t_i) - \textbf{f} (t_{i-1}) \big | \big | $  should be repalced with $ \big | \big | (t_i, \textbf{f}(t_i)) - (t_{i-1}, \textbf{f}(t_{i-1})) \big | \big | $.

Comment: Note the Range of f (f is vector valued). The absolute value symbols there actually refer to the norm. In more modern notation it would be written: $\Vert \mathbf{f}(t_i) - \mathbf{f}(t_{i-1})\Vert$. So what you say you believe it should be is actually what is meant.

Comment: @DavidReed shouldn't it work for the case where $n=1$, that is, where $f$ is a scalar-valued function?  But it seems to me that it doesn't.  I think it doesn't work for $n=2$ either.  That is, if $\mathrm{\textbf{f}}$ is vector-valued function the values of which are represented with an ordered pair, then the function curve would be in $\mathbb{R}^3$, that is in 3-D space, but we are computing line segment lengths ignoring one of the dimentions, namely the $x$ dimention (or the $t$ dimention), altogether!  Am I right?

Comment: No. You're confusing a curve with a graph. A function from an interval to ${\bf R}^2$, say, its graph lives in ${\bf R}^3$, but as a curve it is just the image of $f$, which lives in ${\bf R}^2$. E.g., the image of $f:[0.\pi]\to{\bf R}^2$ given by $f(t)=(\cos t,\sin t)$ is a semicircle in ${\bf R}^2$, while the graph of $f$ lives in ${\bf R}^3$.

Comment: $f(t_i)$ will have $n$ components. In the case of $y=f(x)$ the function $f$ is different.

Comment: @Pooya Let $\mathbf{f}(t) = (t,y(t))$ and it will give you what you are after for the case of a function of one variable. The graph of a scalar-valued function of one variable (e.g. y(x)) necessarily lives in the plane.

Comment: @Shahab It doesn't seem that $f$ is any different.  We are talking about the same $f$.  As I understand it now a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ can have two different geometric representations.  One is the *curve* of $f$ which is a geometric representation of the parameterized vector $f(t)$ in the $\mathbb{R}^n$ space.  And another is the *graph* of $f$ which is the geometric representation of the same function $y=f(x)$ in the $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ space.  The *curve* of $f$ is the image of its $(n+1)$-dimensional *graph* projected in the $\mathbb{R}^n$ space.

Comment: @Pooya I think he means to note the same symbol being used in two different ways ambiguously. ( f being unary in some instances and n-ary in others.)

Comment: @DavidReed Now I see what he means.  But what I said above is still correct regarding the two different yet related geometric representations of an n-ary function.

Comment: I meant for example the $f$ and $\tilde{f}$ in $y=f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and $\tilde{f}(t)=(\cos t,\sin t)$. Clearly here $f\ne \tilde{f}$. The arc length formula refers to the latter $\tilde{f}$, but calls it $f$.

Comment: @Shahab I see.  So as another example, following your notation if we let $y = f(x) = (\cos x, \sin x)$ for $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$, then $\tilde{f}(t) = (t, \cos t, \sin t)$ where $\tilde{f}$ must be used in the arc length formula to find the arc length of the *graph* of $f$.

Comment: No your $f$ is parametrically defining a curve; (the unit circle) and hence the arc length formula applies. I think you need to differentiate between the parametrization and the graph of $f$. The formula refers to the former.

Comment: For example consider the arc length of the line segment from (1,1) to (1,3). This is not the graph of any function. Yet it can be parametrized by $\tilde{f}(t)=(1,t)$ where $t\in [1,3]$. The arc length formula refers to this $\tilde{f}(t)$.

Comment: @Shahab, thanks for the clarification.  Now I see the difference.  So would you say that in the Wikipedia definition, a curve $f$ can be defined more accurately as the following.  Let $f$ be the parametric equation of a curve defined as $f(t) = (f_1(t), f_2(t), ..., f_n(t))$ where $f_i: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ for all $i = 1, 2, ..., n$ are continuously differentiable functions.

Comment: That's a different question regarding the definition of a curve. I suggest you ask it separately.

Comment: "Everyone knows what a curve is, until he has studied enough mathematics to become confused through the countless number of possible exceptions", F. Klein (from Reed & Simon: Methods of modern mathematical physics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have the function $f(t) = (\cos t, \sin t, t).$  This is the parametric equation of a helix.  The length of the curve would be $\int_a^b \|f(t)'\| \ dt$

But you might have learned the arc-length formula for the graph of a function e.g. $y = x^2.$

$L = \int \sqrt {1 + (\frac {dy}{dx})^2} \ dx$

But this curve could just as easily be written $f(t) = (t, t^2)$  And we would be back to the formulation in the first paragraph.